# Finding supremum & infimum

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

$B=a+(2a)^{-1}: a\in \mathbb Q, 0.1≤a≤5$.

What I tried to do is work on the limits,  $0.1≤a≤5 \implies 1/10≤1/2a≤5$
than to find the supremum and infimum. I tried to find the limit for $a+(2a)^{-1}$
which was $1/10≤a+1/2a≤5+1/10$. Making the supremum and maximum to be $5+1/10$ and infimum and min to be $1/10$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when formatting, it makes it much easier to read and makes your question clearer.

Comment: You found out the range of $\frac{1}{2a}$ all fine. But while adding the two inequalities, add all the three parts simultaneously. Your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting $y = f(x) := x + \frac{1}{2x}$ for $0.1\leq x\leq5$ reveals that your answer is incorrect. Although the supremum does appear to occur at the boundary of the interval $[0.1, 5]$, the infimum can be clearly seen to occur in the interior of the interval. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ you can find the infimum by applying the first derivative test for closed intervals to the function $f$.